# How to align text and image in a CSS box?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertically align some text and an image in a CSS box.

I tried several methods, here is the code for the last one I tried called "display:table-cell-method"

```
<div style="border-color:blue; height:200px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
2:38<img src="images/stopwatch-button-play.png">
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the result in the newest version of Firefox: http://screencast.com/t/Yzg2MzAzNW

The image is centered correctly, the text is only centered nearly correctly. It sits at the baseline of the image. Why?

Comment: The guys at doctype.com are great at answering this kind of question.

Comment: yeap. but so are some of us here! :)

Comment: `display: table-cell` outside of a `table-row` will result in undefined behaviour, except in IE6-7 where it will result in no behaviour at all. Don't do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the following

```
<div style="border-color:blue; height:200px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
2:38<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/stopwatch-button-play.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

vertical alignment is thoroughly misunderstood. Have you read [this](http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html)?

as for why the text sites at the baseline of the image, it is because the image and the text are both in the flow of the div. they will not overlap. to have the text centered too (implying it lies *over* the image), you will have to put the text into a `div` or a `span` and adjust its positioning (set it to relative and experiment with left and top).

Cheers

Comment: As a matter of fact: Yes, I did read this, aprox. 90 minutes before I gave up searching the answer with google and posted on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background-position property.

it looks like this.

background: url(path/to/image.whatever) top; //aligns it to the top.

you can even do something like `top left` or `top right` etc.

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) has everything you need to know about backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is only one line high, you can set line-height to the height of your image. It will center the text vertically. Then position:absolute on your image will prevent it from disturbing the positioning of the text in the div:

```
<div style="border-color:blue; height:200px; ">
<div style="line-height:30px;margin-top:85px">2:38<img style="position:absolute" src="images/stopwatch-button-play.png"></div>
</div>
```